# Php nested function p

Tags: php

Hello I don' t know why this code is not working for me . i want to create ul  and inside ul i want to have li elements with some categories from my db ...then i want to make another ul foreach li element with some li elements that contains subcategories from my db. When i cal selectareCategorii()  in index page  i see first the elements from this line $this->selectareSubcategorii($categorii["id_categorie"]) so from the second function then the elements from the first function and i don t know why.

public function selectareCategorii() {

```
         $query = mysqli_query($this->con,"SELECT * FROM categorii");
         while($categorii = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            echo "<ul>
                <li>$categorii[nume_categorie]".

                $this->selectareSubcategorii($categorii["id_categorie"])
                ."</li>
                  </ul>";



         }

     }
     private function selectareSubcategorii($id) {
         $query = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT * FROM subcategorie WHERE categorie_id ='$id'") OR die(mysqli_error($this->con));
         while($subcategorii = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            echo "<li>$subcategorii[subcategorie_nume]</li>";
             $this->selectareSubcategorii1($subcategorii['subcategorie_id']);
         }
     }
```

I want this result`

- FROM FIRST FUNCTION ->selectareCategorii()

  FROM SECOND FUNCTION -> selectareSubcategorii($id)

The result i get in my page is :

FROM SECOND FUNCTION -> selectareSubcategorii($id)

- FROM FIRST FUNCTION ->selectareCategorii()

`

So I don t understand why second function runes first then the content from the first function run...In my head:) i think the content from first function run then find $this->selectareSubcategorii($categorii["id_categorie"]) and run the content from that function then return and run the last lines of code from the first function

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want, you will need to save all the `id_categorie` from the first loop and then use those values to call `selectareSubcategorii()`. Try this:

```
$query = mysqli_query($this->con,"SELECT * FROM categorii");
$id_categorie = array();
echo "<ul>";
while($categorii = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "<li>$categorii[nume_categorie]</li>";
    $id_categorie[] = $categorii["id_categorie"];
}
foreach ($id_categorie as $id) {
    $this->selectareSubcategorii($id);
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: Did this help? Or am I still misunderstanding your question?